# react native : How can TouchableOpacity be displayed or hidden according to the conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can TouchableOpacity be displayed or hidden according to the conditions?
How TouchableOpacity can be viewed or hidden depending on the conditions
Only if the **Sampling_Method_Description** field is not null then TouchableOpacity should be displayed otherwise not displayed.

```
<TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 2,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                left: 120,
                top: 7,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log('EYE PRESSED!!')

              }}
            >
              <MaterialIcons
                size={40}
                name='visibility' 
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

Example = () => {
  const [showButton, setshowButton] = useState(false);

  const renderButton = () => {
    return showButton ? (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          borderRadius: 5,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 2,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: "red",
          left: 120,
          top: 7,
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("EYE PRESSED!!");
        }}>
        <MaterialIcons size={40} name="visibility" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : null;
  };

  return <View>{renderButton()}</View>;
};
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator inside JSX block like so:

```js
return (
  <View>
    {yourConditionIsTrue?
      <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 2,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                left: 120,
                top: 7,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log('EYE PRESSED!!')

              }}
            >
              <MaterialIcons
                size={40}
                name='visibility' 
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
         :
          null }
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `&&` operator :

```
{Sampling_Method_Description && 
  <TouchableOpacity
    //other props
    //...
    //...
/>}
```